# What is Firefox favorites physical location?

Tags: firefox, bookmarks

I am looking to move my Firefox favorites from one machine to another. But for that I am unable to find the physical location of the favorites from where i can copy them.

Does anyone know how to get them?

Comment: Physical location? Most likely on a spinning platter inside a metal casing, screwed into a drive bay, inside your tower next to where your sitting right now. .... sorry couldn't resist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>
- Select Import and backup
- Click on backup
- Restore on destination